# DLLImport get Attempted to read or write protected memory

Tags: c#, delphi, pinvoke, dllimport

I'm going crazy.

I have a dll, with this function :

```
function MyFunc(myId: integer; var LstCB: array of char): integer; stdcall;
```

The first parameter is a poor integer.
But the second one is a char[2048] which get someting like this

```
('9', #13, #10, '8', '8', '8', '8', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '2', '5', '0', '7', #13, #10, '8', '8', '8', '8', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '2', '6', '0',  #13, #10, '8', '8', '8', '8', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '3', '3', '1', '5', #13, #10, #0, #0, #0, #0, #0, #0, #0, #0, #0, #0, #0, #0, #0, #0, #0, #0, #0, #0, #0, #0, #0, #0, #0, #0, #0, #0, #0, #0, #0, #0, #0, #0, #0, #0, #0, #0, #0,....#0)
```

I imported this with DllImport :

```
[DllImport(@"MyDll.dll", EntryPoint = "MyFunc", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
internal static extern int MyFunc(int myId, string list);
```

And I get :

```
Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory has been corrupted.
```

Have you some ideas please ???

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your Delphi function is using an open array for the string parameter. This is not something that should be exposed across a DLL boundary. The protocol for calling an Delphi open array is implementation specific.

You should change your Delphi code to receive a `PChar`.

```
function MyFunc(myId: Integer; LstCB: PChar): Integer; stdcall;
```

If the data is being passed from C# to the Delphi DLL then your P/invoke is fine. If the DLL is meant to return data to the C# code then you need to declare the text parameter as `StringBuilder` in the P/invoke.

```
[DllImport(@"MyDll.dll", EntryPoint = "MyFunc", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
internal static extern int MyFunc(int myId, StringBuilder list);
...
StringBuilder list = new StringBuilder(2048);
int res = MyFunc(ID, list);
string theList = list.ToString();
```

The only other thing to watch out for is what the meaning of `char` is in Delphi. If the DLL is built with Delphi 2009 or later then `char` is a Unicode character and you need to specify the `CharSet` in your P/invoke.

Comment: To elabourate, the reason this fails is that it unbalances the stack. The size of "array of char" (array.Length bytes) is not the same as a C# string pointer (4/8 bytes), so the parameters pollute the stack and result in undefined behaviour.